# Define one font face for several font files with different weight

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I came across this issue using custom fonts. Many offer several files to support different font weights and italics, so you will define a font face like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'WebFont Bold';
  src: url('myfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
       url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype'); /* Chrome 4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+, Safari 3—5 */
}
```

Where **Bold** will be replaced with different font specific words like italic or light. I was wondering is it possible to define one font face that will use specific font, say bold if somewhere in css `font-weight: bold;` is set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do it is like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'WebFont';
  src: url('myfont_regular.woff')....
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'WebFont';
  font-weight: bold;
  src: url('myfont_bold.woff')....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the same name for different font like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('myfont.woff') format('woff'),
       url('myfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('myfont-bold.woff') format('woff'),
       url('myfont-bold.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

And using like:

```
p {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
}
strong {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    font-weight: bold;
}
```